# Header not repeating when the field data is too long

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, msbi

Report header not repeating to next page after exporting to pdf When one column data in a row is going to next page, not sure how to go ahead on this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When submitting a question like this, please also include a [minimal viable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to illustrate the problem. As it is, the problem statement is too broad to be answered without more information.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up,

link(https://imgur.com/a/IbMwk) if you see the image in the link i have four groupings being used in the report, and applying all settings ion the Repeat on New Page section by clicking on Advanced mode and Selecting Static columns.

I am facing Issue when the data in the Detail part is too long and going into next page then table headers are not repeating on new page.